# ModelMultipleChoiceField dosen't work correctly in django form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I need a combobox  in my template. so I use ModelMultipleChoiceField when I try to submit my form It said this field is empty and you must choose !
myform:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
     type_pm = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=IvrModel.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select())
```

my template:

```
{% for field in form %}

     {{ field.label_tag }}
     {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

how do I fix It?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `widget=forms.Select()`. `ModelMultipleChoiceField` expects list of values, not a single value.

Comment: what should I use for single data?

Comment: ModelChoiceField, if data comes from model